# Does it sound natural to say "I have made an unsolicited resignation"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I would like to say I resign before being fired and the company accept that. Can I say:

1. I made an unsolicited resignation.

2.I took the initiative to resign.

3.The company accepts my unsolicited resignation.

thanks in advance

Comment: No. We do not speak of "**making** a resignation."

Comment: Better perhaps: "I resigned." Or: "In anticipation of being fired, I resigned."

Comment: @rajah9 Neither of those seem to have the nuance implied.

Comment: @Greybeard I think it is more helpful to the OP to offer a possibility rather than to raise a criticism. But let's leave that to the OP, shall we?

Comment: What we normally hear is "I resigned voluntarily," or "My resignation was voluntary". I supposed you could also say, "My resignation was unsolicited," but that expression is not commonly used.